# Имя файла. Вывести полное название файла в формате

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Само задание, нужно с клавиатуры вводить название файла и его расширение, затем при помощи строк, нужно соеденить все, поставить точку и вывести

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[128];
    char buffer2[128];
    fgets(buffer1, 128, stdin);
    fgets(buffer2, 128, stdin);
    printf("%s.%s", buffer1, buffer2);
    return 0;
}
```